# Identify which items have rank-deficient issue in a batch r forecast of over 14,500 time series

Tags: r, forecasting

Any ideas on identifying which time series of 14554 are producing the message

> "1: In predict.lm(fit, newdata = data.frame(X)) :   prediction from a
>   rank-deficient fit may be misleading"

When running a batch forecast using the following code:

```
ns <- ncol(UPCts) # Forecasted items
h <- 5 # Forecast periods
cl <- 95  # Confidence level

FcstLo1 <- matrix(NA,nrow=h,ncol=ns)
for(i in 1:ns)
   FcstLo1[,i] <- forecast(UPCts[,i], level=c(cl), h=h, robust = TRUE,
                      find.frequency = TRUE, allow.multiplicative.trend = TRUE)$lower
```

Reviewing data provides suspicions, but identifying precisely would be best.

Comment: `capture.output` returns as a character string the output of a command